# Consuming SOAP webservice using Django

Tags: django, web-services, soap

I have a Django (1.4.3) application an need to consume a SOAP webservice?

But I haven't found anything about that.

What I need is simple, I format the XML using Django (done)

Now I need to post the XML on the endpoint, and check the results.

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I used Suds and it worked fine.